# I am trying to make a program which accepts two numbers and finds the prime, even and odd numbers in between

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program which will accept a starting number and ending number (int) and find the prime, even and odd numbers in between. I am not able to set my if and else conditions properly. It would be great if someone could even tell me a simpler method.

```
package proj2;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Proj2
{
    public void number(int sn,int en)
    {
        if (sn <= en)
        {   
            int number = 2;
            if (sn > number && sn % number != 0)
            {
                System.out.println(sn + " : " + "Prime");
                number++;
                sn++;
                number(sn++,en);
            }
            else if (sn % 2 == 0)
            {
                System.out.println(sn + " : " + "Even");
                sn++;
                number(sn++,en);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(sn + " : " + "Odd");
                sn++;
                number(sn,en);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] abc)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the starting number:");
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the ending number:");
        int y = sc.nextInt();

        Proj2 p = new Proj2();
        p.number(x,y);     
    }
}
```

Comment: For starters: all your cases call `number` recursively again, this will not work. And why are you trying to it recursively in the first place instead of simply looping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being prime and odd are not mutually exclusive, your primality test is incorrect, and you are recursively calling `number()`. Instead use:

```
private boolean isPrime(int num){
    // assuming positive ints
    if( num <= 2 || num % 2 == 0) 
        return false;
    for(int divisor = 3; divisor <= (int)Math.pow(num, 0.5); divisor+=2)
        if( num % divisor == 0) 
            return false;
    return true
}

public void number(int start, int end){
    if( start <= end ){
        for( int curr = start; curr <= end; curr++ ){
            if( curr % 2 == 1 ) {
                System.out.println(curr + " : Odd");
                if(isPrime(curr))
                    System.out.println(curr + " : Prime");
            } else System.out.println(curr + " : Even");
        }
    }
```